# Correct way to store a bit array

Tags: mysql, binary

I'm working on a project that needs to store something like

```
 101110101010100011010101001
```

into the database. It's not a file or archive: it's only a bit array, and I think that storing it into a varchar column is waste of space/performance.

I've searched about the BLOB and the VARBINARY type. But both of then allows to insert a value like 54563423523515453453, that's not exactly a bit array.

For sure, if I store a bit array like 10001000 into a BLOB/varbinary/varchar column, it will consume more than a byte, and I want that the minimum space is consumed. In the case of eight bits, it needs to consume only one byte, 16 bits two bytes, and so on.

If it's not possible, then what is the best approach to waste the minimum amount of space in this case?

Important notes: The size of the array is variable, and is not divisible by eight in every situation. Sometimes I will need to store 325 bits, other times 7143 bits....

Answer (score 0):

Binary is a string representation of a number. The string

```
101110101010100011010101001
```

represents the number

`... + 1*25 + 0*24 + 1*23 + 0*22 + 0*21 + 1*20`

As such, it can be stored in a 32-bit integer if were to be converted from a binary string to the number it represents. In Perl, one would use

```
oct('0b'.$binary)
```

But you have a variable number of bits. Not a problem! Just process them 8 at a time to create a string of bytes to place in a BLOB or similar.

Ah, but there's a catch. You'll need to add padding to get a number divisible by 8, which means you'll have to use a means of removing that padding. A simple approach if there's a known maximum length is to use a length prefix. e.g. If you know the number of bits is never going to exceed 65,535, encode the number of bits in the first two bytes of the string.

```
pack('nB*', length($binary), $binary)
```

which is reverted using

```
my ($length, $binary) = unpacked('nB*', $packed);
substr($binary, $length) = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of my previous projects, I converted streams of 1's and 0' to decimal, but they were shorter. I dont know if that would be applicable in your project.

On the other hand, imho, you should clarify what will you need to do with that data once you get it stored. Search? Compare? It might largely depend on the purpose of the database.

Could you gzip it and then store it? Is that applicable?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a bit complex to explain, but in resume, I have a bool[] in my code, and I only want to store, and after that, select it as is.

Comment: If the storage space is only concern you should probably use some method of compression and store it compressed imho